# PHP get real date from offline pc

Tags: php

I am creating offline php system to a client and I want to get the exact date **without internet** and also in the consideration that user **can change** the PC time so what is the solution?

Comment: If the computer isn't connected to the internet, and you don't trust the computers time, your out of luck. Unless want to you ask the user to enter it manually every time (pardon the pun) the user opens the page?

Comment: Please consider posting the code to what you have tried so far next time. As far as the date/time is considered - the php `<?php echo(date("Y-m-d",$t)); ?>` would work, if the computer could get the date from somewhere.

Comment: I believe the `date()` function does use the system time, so it will use the correct or incorrect time from the system it is hosted on.

Comment: yes exactly thats the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

date() will use the system time, unless otherwise specified not to. That being said, you cannot avoid the user from changing their system clock. If you want to make sure date and time are not changed by the user, use the internet to validate. Since you must be offline, you'll just have to trust the user.

Comment: thats the problem.. I am trying to find a solution that solve this problem :D

Comment: He may try to access the systems camera and take a current picture of the starry sky and find an algorithm to calculate the time by the stars. But it suspect it will be hard doing that with php.

Comment: sorry for sarcasm but you cannot solve this without the internet or a atomic clock hardware component which is accessable by php.

Comment: @steven hahahahahha :D :D

Comment: actually there is something u can do.. Save a file called counter.php and a variable called `$counter = 0`  .. User AJAX and PHP to increase that counter by 1 every 1 hour using Setintervel function in JQuery or JS.. Then check after all `if($counter == 30)` which mean it is equal to 30 hour then close the program and end the free trial.. 

But user can find this file and edit it so it is not secured..

Comment: @user7431257 I suspected it should work after a restart, too. So your idea requires to have the computer, the script and the browser running all the time.

Comment: nope because it will always get the old time from the same file @steven